# Power BI Calendar visualisation

Tags: calendar, powerbi, dax, visualization

I have a problem. I am kind of new to Power BI and I try to make a Calender Visual in Power BI, where you can see the events in a month.

I have search my problem on Google but I didn't find anything. I Also tried all the visualisations in Power BI, The Calender visualisation with MAQ Software is far out the best But I can't achieve the results with my data.

My data is as following

```
Project ID  Start project planning phase execution phase Monitor phase Live
22193      18-01-2021      20-01-2021      28-01-2021    20-02-2021     03-03-2021
29193      20-01-2021      10-02-2021      15-02-2021    19-03-2021  
87596      25-02-2021      10-03-2021      25-03-2021
```

As you can see, I have 5 phases, each with his own DateTime. So 1 Project with his Project ID can have at least 1 and maximum 5 phases.

The problem is: The Calender visualisations in Power BI can only work if you have 2 dates (start and end). But as you can see I in my data, every phase has a start date of the phase.

For example. Here below is The MAQ software visualisation. It is a good visualisation but it only works with 2 dates,

[image]

*(You can assume that the end date of a phase is the start date of the next phase
for example, the "start phase" with Project ID"22193" starts at 18-01-2021 and ends at 20-01-2021
And the " Planning phase" with Project ID"22193" starts on 20-01-2021 and ends on 28-01-2021 etc.)*

Somebody that can Help me with this problem?

Yours faithfully

EDIT: restructuring my data as follow? Will it Work?

```
Phase ID |  Project ID |  Phase |     |Start    |   | End | 
1        |  22193      |  Start |     |18-1-2021|   |20-1-2021 
2        |  22193      |  Planning|   |20-1-2021|   |28-1-2021 
3        |  22193      |  Execition|  |28-1-2021|   |20-2-2021 
4        |  22193      |  Monitor |   |20-2-2021|   |03-03-2021 
5        |  22193      |  Live |      |         |   |03-03-2021
```

Comment: Consider unpivoting your data

Comment: Hi Rado, how do you mean Unpivoting?

Comment: Restructure your data to have only one project phase per record, then compute effective start and end dates for each record.

Comment: Hi @RADO, Thank you for your replay. I am kind of new to Power BI so thats is why I am asking the following. Will restructure my data also affect my SQL database Or the restructure  data only remain in Power BI? I Currently work on an Excel sheet, but in the furture the dashboard must connect to a SQL Server. And IF I restructure my data like you said. What do you think about the Edit in my post?

Comment: @RADO,
What is your opinion about my last comment?